# Is there any automation script where we can validate the tags quickly?

Tags: javascript, testing, google-analytics, adobe, adobe-analytics

I Just wanted to know, is there any automation script where i can validate the tags very quickly.Because my client is moving akamai to self hosting option in adobe DTM.

Once they moved to self hosting, i have to validate all the tags.which is not possible.

Is there anyway?

Where i can validate quickly whole site tags.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for software recommendations is off-topic. There is a stackexchange site for recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are tools for such a thing- Observepoint or Hubscan, for instance (which are more focused on the analytics beacons), or Tagtician (focused more specifically on DTM). Unfortunately, I don't know of any FREE tool or DIY way to validate tags on your site.

Comment: Thanks @jenn I will try Hubscan.